# occupancy - 2 approaches give different answers

Tags: combinatorics

6 people enter 3 rooms, independently deciding which room to enter, with equal probability of deciding which room to enter. What is the probability that room #1 will have only one person?

By "stars and bars" this is would be the number of ways 5 people could occupy 2 rooms, divided by the total number of ways 6 people could occupy 3 rooms: 
6C1 / 8C2 or about 0.214
The other approach would first select the person to go into room #1 (6 ways), then each of the 5 remaining people can pick room #2 or room #3. That is the numerator; the total number of configurations (the denominator) is 3^6 --> 
(6 * 2^5) / 3^6 , about 0.2633

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on if your people are indistinguishable or not. If they are indistinguishable, solution 1 is correct, if they can be distinguished, solution 2 is correct.

The first solution answers the question: What is the probability that one person is in room #1 if we are only interested in the number of people in each room (indistinguishable people). Usually, people are distinguishable, that's why I would suggest that solution 2 is correct.

Comment: If the ping pong balls were numbered to make them distinct, would that mean there would be a different probability of having 1 ping pong ball in box 1, vs leaving the balls indistinguishable? That is very counter-intuitive, which probably means it is correct.

Comment: It may seem counter-intuitive, but the probability will indeed change. Here's why: If the balls are numbered you will get way more different possibilities of distributing them. It's different if you distribute them `|13|2|4|` or `|12|3|4|`.  However, with unnumbered balls you are no longer interested in the position of each single ball - it's generalizing them, they're not individuals, but a crowd. In that case the above distributions would be `|**|*|*|` and `|**|*|*|` which clearly is equal. That's why 'stars and bars' are used in the last case

Comment: very cool. Thank you.